# How to make 1 gateway serve 2 tenants? or can we have 2 gateways on the same computer?

Tags: powerbi

I am planning for datasets for multiple Power BI tenants that use the same SQL datasource located on-prem.

How to make 1 gateway serve 2 tenants? or can we have 2 gateways on the same computer?